# Python to PHP byte string conversion

Tags: python, php

I am trying to convert this Python code into PHP but I got stuck on handling bytes data. Can someone help me fix this PHP code so I can get the same result as Python which is **2734**?

PYTHON VERSION

```
indexes = [8, 13, 23, 13, 37, 23, 31, 11, 8, 37, 23, 27, 12, 9, 21, 20, 6, 8, 12, 16, 12, 17, 35, 37, 35, 28, 13, 35, 9, 31, 2, 25]
sha_1_sign = 'cf493b66e356e588c545df7dda24ed4d404f1c90'
sha_1_b = sha_1_sign.encode("ascii")
checksum = sum([sha_1_b[number] for number in indexes])
print(checksum)
#result 2734
```

PHP VERSION

```
$indexes = [8, 13, 23, 13, 37, 23, 31, 11, 8, 37, 23, 27, 12, 9, 21, 20, 6, 8, 12, 16, 12, 17, 35, 37, 35, 28, 13, 35, 9, 31, 2, 25];
$sha_1_sign = 'cf493b66e356e588c545df7dda24ed4d404f1c90';
$sha_1_b = hex2bin($sha_1_sign);  
$checksum = 0;
foreach ($indexes as $number) {
    if (isset($sha_1_b[$number])) {
        $checksum += ord($sha_1_b[$number]);
    }
}
echo $checksum; 
#result 2047
```

Comment: The PHP version converts `cf493b66e356e588c545df7dda24ed4d404f1c90` from hex to a series of bytes, whereas Python interprets it just as a string, not as hex. So in the Python code, `sha_1_b` is 40 bytes long, `sha_1_b[0]` is 99 (ASCII code for 'c'), `sha_1_b[1]` is 102 (ASCII code for 'f') and so on. In the PHP, `$sha_1_b` is 20 bytes long; `$sha_1_b[0]` is 207 (the byte represented by hex `cf`) and so on.

Comment: Long story short, are you sure the Python code is correct? If it is, you can make the PHP code do the same as the Python simply by removing the `hex2bin` and doing `$sha_1_b = $sha_1_sign;`

Comment: @slothrop the python code works fine with python3 sorry if I didn't mention it. So what can you suggest for php? Is there any solution? Thanks

Comment: Just replacing `$sha_1_b = hex2bin($sha_1_sign);` with `$sha_1_b = $sha_1_sign;` will do the same thing as the Python and give 2734. (Or just remove the `$sha_1_b` variable and replace its usages with `$sha_1_sign`.)

Comment: Thank you @slothrop  I just got the solution, is perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python code treats each individual character as a separate entity, and takes the ASCII value of it. The PHP code converts the hex string to its binary representation, and then tries to refer to it as an array. I'd change it by splitting into an array of single characters first, then mapping each of those characters to their ASCII values. Then just use the number from `$indexes` as the index of the value to add:

```php
$indexes = [...];
$sha_1_sign = 'cf493b66e356e588c545df7dda24ed4d404f1c90';
$sha_1_b = array_map(fn($a) => ord($a), str_split($sha_1_sign));
$checksum = 0;
foreach ($indexes as $number) {
    $checksum += $sha_1_b[$number];
}
echo $checksum;
```

Or you can one-line it, by mapping each value in `$indexes` to its associated index in `$sha_1_b`, and then summing the resulting mapped array:

```php
$indexes = [...];
$sha_1_sign = 'cf493b66e356e588c545df7dda24ed4d404f1c90';
$sha_1_b = array_map(fn($a) => ord($a), str_split($sha_1_sign));
$checksum = array_sum(array_map(fn($a) => $sha_1_b[$a], $indexes));
echo $checksum;
```

You might also use PHP's little-used string-as-array feature, which allows you to refer to a character in a string via the array syntax. I'm not a big fan of this notation though, because it can be confusing for other people to look at your code, who might think the reference is an array when it's really a string:

```php
$sha_1_sign = 'cf493b66e356e588c545df7dda24ed4d404f1c90';
$checksum = 0;
foreach ($indexes as $number) {
    $checksum += ord($sha_1_sign[$number]);
}
echo $checksum;
```

Or, the super short version:

```php
$indexes = [...];
$sha_1_sign = 'cf493b66e356e588c545df7dda24ed4d404f1c90';
$checksum = array_sum(array_map(fn($a) => ord($sha_1_sign[$a]), $indexes));
echo $checksum;
```

Comment: Awsome! The third solution is perfect for my PHP version also.  Thank you alot Alex!

Comment: If you find the string-as-array notation undesirable, you could of course just use substr: `$checksum = array_sum(array_map(fn($a) => ord(substr($sha_1_sign, $a)), $indexes));`